# How to disable intellij auto change my code format?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I edit the java source code, intellij will auto format my code besides the places I edit, how to disable that ?

Comment: IntelliJ normally only formats the code when you request it - did you change the default?

Comment: I don't change anything ? how to config that ? didn't found that

Comment: Are you talking about auto formatting when you commit via IntelliJ? What you're apparently trying to turn off is a feature lots of people request. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5806

Comment: CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-L shows the iinteractive dialog for formating.  One option there is to "restrict formating" to VCS changed lines. See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/reformat-code-dialog.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the latest IntelliJ Idea (2021.3), Auto formatting can be stopped for one or more file type by going to

`Preferences` -> `Tools` -> `Actions on save` -> `Enable or Disable Reformatting action for one or more file type`

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In my case intellij was messing with all the spaces in the code.
So, I changed following settings :

**Editor > General**

[image]

Comment: You can go to the IntelliJ Settings cmd + ; (as Mac, else go as windows) then select CodeStyle and apply the default code style. It will apply default code formating as per what programming language you're using.

Comment: God every time I create a new project there are like 100 "smart" auto BS settings I need to disable so I don't waste hours of my time sifting through garbage diffs

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who want to disable formatting just for some specific file(s), there is a way since 2018.3 ([IDEA-97848](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97848)).

Go to `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Formatter` and add your exclusion pattern(s).

Answer (score 1):

I tried disabling trim trailing spaces in code formatting but this doesn't work for my file type '.erb'.

I added my file type '.erb' to selectively disable code inspection for this file type but this doesn't work in IntelliJ version 2016.2.4.

I locked my file after I had made the changes using the lock icon in the Status Bar and this finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

In `Preferences > Tools > Actions on save` you have a definition

BUT that can be overwritten by the following one, so check in that order:

In `Preferences > Editor > Code style > [language]` uncheck `reformat on file save`.

**Update**: None of those worked for me, so I change my file, commit without save (DON'T save during commit to avoid data loss, you'll be prompted) and then CTRL-Z.
Your file is committed and saved but only with your changes.

---

FWIW, I'm using Scala, on IntelliJ Community 2021.2, with the Scala plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to disable formatting for a particular file. I used Do not format fields under, `File > Setting > Code Style > Formatter` tab. The pattern can be changed as per the requirement.

Version: IntelliJ Community Edition 2023

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable format in a specific block/area use //@formatter annotation

```
//@formatter:off
//Your auto format disabled code.
//@formatter:on
```

Answer (score -2):

You *can* disable IntelliJ IDEA's ability to format (and therefore auto format) specific file types, but it comes at a cost.

To disable :

1. Settings > Editor > File Types
2. Select the file type you want to have *never* formatted
3. change the extension to something you don't use - for example '*.styl' to '*.oldstyl'

Now, even if you tell IntelliJ to reformat one of these files it won't.

The cost is that you lose syntax highlighting and language support all together.
In my case for stylus files it was worth it.
IDEA kept removing tab characters in sections of code that I wasn't even working in.  SUPER annoying and destructive.

Comment: I do not think it's a good practice to break ide in order to prevent it from doing something you don't want it to do

Comment: @Agil then IDE should provide us with the option to do what we want it to do :)